# Objective-c паттерн модель-вид-контроллер

Tags: model, controller, шаблоны-проектирования, view

В общем не давно изучаю Obj-c, прочитал про очень интересный паттерн модель-вид-контролле, никак не могу применить на практике (для кастомных ячеек таблицы получилось). Но как быть с контроллером, к примеру, у меня есть **контроллер** - (**FirstViewController**) и **вид** - (**FirstView**). В **IB** я указал, что контроллер это - FirstViewController.h вид - FirstView.h. На вид добавил пару лейблов, но я даже их перетащить не могу луйблы в класс **FirstView.h** из **IB**.

Как же так? Что я делаю не верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы явно что-то не так делаете. Создайте 2 класса, к примеру:

```
FirstView : UIView
FirstController : UIViewController
```

Задайте эти классы:

[image]

[image]

Объявите лейбл в **FirstView**.

[image]

Объявите **FirstView** в **FirstController**.

[image]

И последний шаг:

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало :)